# Migrating file from one org to other

Tags: data-migration

I have been working on Data Migration from Salesforce to Salesforce.

For  Attachment to ContentDocument I have got a good article - https://www.simplysfdc.com/2018/02/salesforce-mass-upload-files-to-files.html.  but couldn't find an article for ContentDocument/ContentNotes to ContentDocument/ContentNotes Migration.

I am looking for migrating files to files. When I extract contentversion with Dataloder.io then files are coming in csv, and then csv become 800mb  impossible to upload.
Another approach, export the content version data, I am getting all content version files with ID name and some Unix format. If I upload those files, Most of them are getting created in docx. FILETYPE is not creatable in content version

Comment: For attachments, it would be easier to use this tool to convert them to ContentDocument and then you can migrate just the ContentDocument: https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCheng, I don't know how to migrate the ContentDocument from one org to another.. I exported the Content version from one org and try to upload in another but didn't work because of file size. I tried the data export feature, and export all content version records but file are coming in some Unix format.

Comment: @amidstCloud, Were you able to find solution for this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Satrang Mass File Download AppExchange App and Dataloader, Using Satrang  Mass File Download you can export all files and attachments along with CSV files and import these files with ParentIds in the new org.

URL - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ&tab=e

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Mass File Download AppExchange App.

Comment: Thank you for disclosing your affiliation!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to data loader, but actually working with files is [XL-Connector](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler/). It will save the files locally when doing a SOQL query, and then you can upload them from the local disk and link to respective records without having to deal with multiple CSV files and relationships, it creates all the junction records automatically:
[image]